# CS50(2019) problem set "Filter": "blur" somehow not working correctly

Tags: c, cs50

So, I have spent about 5 hours+ trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. I have tried debug50 with a 3x3 file I have manually created in Paint and everything seemed to work as intended; each pixel makes a 3x3 sweep around itself and disregards pixels that do not exist, like the ones in the corners or around edges. The final average values for each of the colors were also correct. Somehow, though, when I checked with check50, it gave out the following message:

[image]

With countless tweaking and head-scratching, I have decided that it was probably time for me to turn to the community for help. Here's my code:

```
{
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            int avgfordiv = 0;
            int neighvalgreen = 0;
            int neighvalblue = 0;
            int neighvalred = 0;

            for (int hh = -1; hh < 2; hh++)
            {
                for (int ww = -1; ww < 2; ww++)
                {
                    if ((h+hh) != height && (w+ww) != width && (h+hh) != -1 && (w+ww) != -1)
                    {
                        //sweep
                        avgfordiv++;//count up for division
                        neighvalgreen += image[h + hh][w + ww].rgbtGreen;
                        neighvalred += image[h + hh][w + ww].rgbtRed;
                        neighvalblue += image[h + hh][w + ww].rgbtBlue;
                    }
                }
            }
            //add values to pixels
             image[h][w].rgbtGreen = (int)(round((float)neighvalgreen / avgfordiv));
             image[h][w].rgbtBlue = (int)(round((float)neighvalblue / avgfordiv));
             image[h][w].rgbtRed = (int)(round((float)neighvalred / avgfordiv));

            //check cap
             if (image[h][w].rgbtGreen <= 255)
                {}
            else
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen %= 255;

            if (image[h][w].rgbtRed <= 255)
                {}
            else
                image[h][w].rgbtRed %= 255;

            if (image[h][w].rgbtBlue <= 255)
                {}
            else
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue %= 255;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: You could replace each of the last 3 `if` statements with `image[h][w].thing %= 256;`

Answer (score 2):

Making a copy of the image and using that copy to calculate the total amount of red green and blue seems to fix it.

```
RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
for (int h = 0; h < height; i++)
{
    for (int w = 0; w < width; j++)
    {
        copy[h][w] = image[h][w];
    }
}
```

And change it below:

```
neighvalgreen += copy[h + hh][w + ww].rgbtGreen;
neighvalred += copy[h + hh][w + ww].rgbtRed;
neighvalblue += copy[h + hh][w + ww].rgbtBlue;
```

Also you dont need to check if the values exceeded 255 because you are calculating the average value so it will never exceeded 255.

Comment: making a copy works because if you change the original values before getting all the averages then you won't have the correct results.  using a copy to read from and then writing results to the original image is the way to go.  thanks for your code snippet, saved me the hassle, lol

Answer (score 1):

My strategy in pseudocode is as follows:

1. Save entire image as a tmp
2. loop through every single pixel
3. For every pixel, image a 3x3 square with the said pixel at the center. Check each of the pixel of the 3x3 square if it exists. If it does, add up the sum. Finally calculate average

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //store entire image in tmp to maintain original value
    RGBTRIPLE tmp[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            tmp[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    //loop through each pixel
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            float n = 0, r = 0, b = 0, g = 0;
                
            // loop the 9box
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++)
            {
                for (int jj = 0; jj < 3; jj++)
                {
                    //calculate average. ONLY if that pixel exists.
                    if ((i + ii - 1 >= 0 && i + ii - 1 < height) && (j + jj - 1 >= 0 && j + jj - 1 < width))
                    {
                        b = b + (float)tmp[i + ii - 1][j + jj - 1].rgbtBlue;
                        r = r + (float)tmp[i + ii - 1][j + jj - 1].rgbtRed;
                        g = g + (float)tmp[i + ii - 1][j + jj - 1].rgbtGreen;
                        n++;
                    }                        
                }
            }
                
            //calculate
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (int)round(b / n);
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = (int)round(r / n);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (int)round(g / n);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a completely different code and got the same error and the same numbers.
But someone wrote this code which works perfectly:

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE ogImage[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            ogImage[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0, red, green, blue, counter; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            red = green = blue = counter = 0;

            if (i >= 0 && j >= 0)
            {
                red += ogImage[i][j].rgbtRed;
                green += ogImage[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                blue += ogImage[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if (i >= 0 && j - 1 >= 0)
            {
                red += ogImage[i][j-1].rgbtRed;
                green += ogImage[i][j-1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += ogImage[i][j-1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if ((i >= 0 && j + 1 >= 0) && (i >= 0 && j + 1 < width))
            {
                red += ogImage[i][j+1].rgbtRed;
                green += ogImage[i][j+1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += ogImage[i][j+1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if (i - 1 >= 0 && j >= 0)
            {
                red += ogImage[i-1][j].rgbtRed;
                green += ogImage[i-1][j].rgbtGreen;
                blue += ogImage[i-1][j].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if (i - 1 >= 0 && j - 1 >= 0)
            {
                red += ogImage[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed;
                green += ogImage[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += ogImage[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if ((i - 1 >= 0 && j + 1 >= 0) && (i - 1 >= 0 && j + 1 < width))
            {
                red += ogImage[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed;
                green += ogImage[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += ogImage[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if ((i + 1 >= 0 && j >= 0) && (i + 1 < height && j >= 0))
            {
                red += ogImage[i+1][j].rgbtRed;
                green += ogImage[i+1][j].rgbtGreen;
                blue += ogImage[i+1][j].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if ((i + 1 >= 0 && j - 1 >= 0) && (i + 1 < height && j - 1 >= 0))
            {
                red += ogImage[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed;
                green += ogImage[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += ogImage[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if ((i + 1 >= 0 && j + 1 >= 0) && (i + 1 < height && j + 1 < width))
            {
                red += ogImage[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed;
                green += ogImage[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += ogImage[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red / (counter * 1.0));
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green / (counter * 1.0));
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue / (counter * 1.0));
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

I know it's late but maybe it will be helpful for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

For future people in doubt

You don't need that much conditions, just think that you are working with one matrix within another.

Once this is done, just place a condition, in case the location being worked does not exceed the matrix limits.

Example

current line + the submatrix line cannot be less than zero, because that would be going beyond the limits.

L: matrix line

sL: submatrix line

[L + sL] [0] ! < 0

[0 + (-1) [0] would be extrapolating.

Just think now for the other cases as well.

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
    {
        // average of the ORIGINAL value of the pixels around it
        int avgR, avgG, avgB, counter;

        // make a copy of the original image for the calculations

        RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];

        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
        {
            for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
            {
                copy[h][w] = image[h][w];
            }
        }

        // go across the image
        for (int linha = 0; linha < height; linha++)
        {
            for (int coluna = 0; coluna < width; coluna++)
            {
                // initialize the variables and reset them to 0
                avgR = 0;
                avgG = 0;
                avgB = 0;
                counter = 0;
                // go across the pixels around
                for (int row = -1; row < 2; row++)
                {
                    for (int column = -1; column < 2; column++)
                    {
                        if (linha + row < 0 || coluna + column < 0 || linha + row >= height || coluna + column >= width)
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            avgR += copy[linha + row][coluna + column].rgbtRed;
                            avgG += copy[linha + row][coluna + column].rgbtGreen;
                            avgB += copy[linha + row][coluna + column].rgbtBlue;
                            counter ++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                image[linha][coluna].rgbtRed = round(avgR / (float) counter);
                image[linha][coluna].rgbtGreen = round(avgG / (float) counter);
                image[linha][coluna].rgbtBlue = round(avgB / (float) counter);
            }
        }

        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fernando's answer is great (I don't have the rep to comment directly on it), but to handle the edge cases, I turned the pixel's for loop's start and end points into variables that get adjusted if you're working with an edge ("i" and "j" are my outer loop counters):

```
            int startRow = -1;
            int endRow = 1;
            int startColumn = -1;
            int endColumn = 1;

            // Handle edge cases
            if (i + startRow < 0) { startRow = 0; }
            if (j + startColumn < 0) { startColumn = 0; }
            if (i + endRow >= height) { endRow = 0; }
            if (j + endColumn >= width) { endColumn = 0; }

            // go across the pixels around
            for (int pxRow = startRow; pxRow <= endRow; pxRow++) {
                for (int pxColumn = startColumn; pxColumn <= endColumn; pxColumn++) {
                    int row = i + pxRow;
                    int column = j + pxColumn;

                    avgR += copy[row][column].rgbtRed;
                    avgG += copy[row][column].rgbtGreen;
                    avgB += copy[row][column].rgbtBlue;
                    counter ++;
                }
            }
```