# CS50 '21 middle pixel incorrect

Tags: c, cs50

Got stuck in week 4 of CS50 2021 with the blur filter. So far I get the pixels on the edge and in the corner correctly, but my middle pixel gets the wrong first value.

Input file: https://ibb.co/4JCdx2x

- Expected output: 127 140 149
- Actual output: 126 140 149

Couldn't find the mistake, so would be thankful for your input ;)

What's missing for the middle pixel to be correct? I assume the last two errors "blur correctly filters 3x3 image" and "blur correctly filters 4x4 image" will be solved by that.

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < width; k++)
        {
            int counted = 0;

            int red = 0;
            int green = 0;
            int blue = 0;
            
            //iterate through the column, from -1 to +1
            for (int h = -1; h < 2; h++)
            {
                //iterate similarly through rows
                for (int w = -1; w < 2; w++)
                {
                    //avoid pixels outside the image (column)
                    if (i + h < 0 || i + h > (height - 1))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                    //avoid pixels outside the image (row)
                    if (k + w  < 0 || k + w > (width - 1))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                    //sum up all values
                    blue += image[i + h][k + w].rgbtBlue;
                    red += image[i + h][k + w].rgbtRed;
                    green += image[i + h][k + w].rgbtGreen;
                    counted++;
                    
                }
            }
            temp[i][k].rgbtRed = red / counted;
            temp[i][k].rgbtGreen = green / counted;
            temp[i][k].rgbtBlue = blue / counted;

        }
    }
    
    // overwrite actual array with temp array
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < width; k++)
        {
            image[i][k] = temp[i][k];
        }
    }

    return;
    
}
```

Comment: No one can help you if don't share the sample input that corresponds to your expected output.

Comment: My psychic powers suggest it's just a minor rounding error. `{126 140 149}` is pretty darn close to `{127 140 149}`.  Does it matter?  Consider using floating point division for your `red/counted` and similar division expressions and then `ceil` or `round` as appropriate to case the value back to int.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that integer division rounds down; like `1151/9 == 127.8888 == 127`. To fix that and get it rounded to the nearest value, add a bias of "the smallest fraction less than half the divisor" to the numerator; like `(1151 + 4.499999)/9 == 128.3888 == 128`.

For graphics, it'd be close enough to use use "half of 1 less than the divisor" as the bias. It won't be 100% perfect for all possible values, but any difference from perfect rounding will be rare and unnoticeable.

In other words:

```
    unsigned int rounding_bias = (counted - 1) / 2;
    temp[i][k].rgbtRed = (red + rounding_bias ) / counted;
    temp[i][k].rgbtGreen = (green + rounding_bias) / counted;
    temp[i][k].rgbtBlue = (blue + rounding_bias) / counted;
```

One alternative is to use floating point division and `round()` to convert back to integer. This will be slightly better for quality, but all the conversions between integer and floating point will have performance costs.

Another alternative (that won't make much sense until later) is to use lookup tables, like `temp[i][k].rgbtRed = lookup_table[counted][red];`, but not necessarily like that (see unrelated performance notes).

**Unrelated Performance Notes**

*Note: I'm going to focus on 3x3 blur filters; but everything I mention can also improve other filters - you'll need different code for each different blur filter.*

To improve performance you can "peel off" the first iteration/s of the outer loop and the last iteration/s of the outer loop. If you do that; (for a 3x3 blur filter) for the first iteration you know it will always be dealing with the top edge, for all middle iterations you know it will never have to worry about the top or bottom edge, and for the last iteration you know it will always be dealing with the bottom edge. This lets you rip out some of the branches, etc.

In the same way, you can "peel off" the first and last iterations of the `for (int k = 0; k < width; k++)` inner loops. If you do that; (for a 3x3 blur filter) you've effectively split it up into 9 areas: top/left corner, top/middle edge, top/right corner; middle/left edge, middle/middle, middle/right edge; bottom/left corner; bottom/middle edge, and bottom/right corner.

Once you do that you can:

a) determine the totals without the overhead of using more inner loops; and delete the `for (int h = -1; h < 2; h++)` and `for (int w = -1; w < 2; w++)` loops.

b) delete all of the edge detection branches, delete the `counted` variable, and use constants for `rounding_bias` and `counted`.

c) Use multiple lookup tables where each one is designed for a specific "already known constant" divisor, like `temp[i][k].rgbtRed = lookup_table_for_9_counted[red];`.

E.g. for the majority of the work (the pixels in the "middle/middle" area, for a 3x3 blur filter) it might be like:

```
for (int k = 1; k < width-1; k++) {
    blue = image[i-1][k-1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][k].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][k+1].rgbtBlue +
            image[i][k-1].rgbtBlue + image[i][k].rgbtBlue + image[i][k+1].rgbtBlue +
            image[i+1][k-1].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][k].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][k+1].rgbtBlue;
    red = image[i-1][k-1].rgbtRed+ image[i-1][k].rgbtRed + image[i-1][k+1].rgbtRed+
            image[i][k-1].rgbtRed+ image[i][k].rgbtRed + image[i][k+1].rgbtRed+
            image[i+1][k-1].rgbtRed+ image[i+1][k].rgbtRed + image[i+1][k+1].rgbtRed;
    green = image[i-1][k-1].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][k].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][k+1].rgbtGreen +
            image[i][k-1].rgbtGreen+ image[i][k].rgbtGreen; + image[i][k+1].rgbtGreen +
            image[i+1][k-1].rgbtGreen+ image[i+1][k].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][k+1].rgbtGreen;

    temp[i][k].rgbtRed = (red + 4 ) / 9;
    temp[i][k].rgbtGreen = (green + 4) / 9;
    temp[i][k].rgbtBlue = (blue + 4) / 9;
}
```

For the temporary buffer; you have a choice - you can:

a) choose to put new pixel values in the temporary buffer

b) choose to put old pixel values in the temporary buffer

c) choose to put the "horizontal sums" of pixel values in the temporary buffer.

For the kind of blur you're doing; the last option is fastest because most of the additions used for calculating the (red, blue, green) totals can be recycled (but you will need to use a different/larger data type - you can't store the sum of three 8-bit values into an 8-bit value). E.g. like:

```
    temp[i+1][k].rgb16tBlue = image[i+1][k-1].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][k].rgbtBlue; + image[i+1][k+1].rgbtBlue;
    blue = temp[i-1][k].rgb16tBlue + temp[i][k].rgb16tBlue + temp[i][k].rgb16tBlue;
```

In addition; for the temporary buffer you can improve performance (make more efficient use of caches) by also using a significantly smaller "rotating buffer" of 3 only lines (for a 3x3 blur filter - it'd be 4 lines for a 4x4 blur filter, etc). E.g. if you chose to put old pixel values in the temporary buffer, then you'd copy 3 lines in at the start; then when you finish the top line you'd move the 4th line of old pixels into the first line of the buffer, then when you finish the 2nd line you'd move the 5th line of old pixels into the 2nd line of the buffer, etc.

**Unrelated Quality Notes**

The algorithm you're using for blur is relatively bad. The problem is that blur is supposed to be done on a circle and you're using a square; and this will cause the image to look like there's more diagonal blur than horizontal/vertical blur. To fix that you can use weights (e.g. corner pixels only count as a fraction for the totals).

This can be used to improve quality and performance at the same time by ensuring that weights are a power of 2, and the sum of all weights is a power of 2. This allows the compiler to replace divisions and multiplications with faster shifts for the majority of the work. For example (using 75% as the weights for corner pixels):

```
    blue = ((image[i-1][k-1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][k+1].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][k-1].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][k+1].rgbtBlue) * 3) / 4 +
            image[i-1][k].rgbtBlue + 
            image[i][k-1].rgbtBlue + image[i][k].rgbtBlue; + image[i][k+1].rgbtBlue +
            image[i+1][k].rgbtBlue;

    temp[i][k].rgbtBlue = (blue + 3) / 8;
```

In this case, the final `(blue + 4) / 9` (which the compiler would probably optimize into "multiplication by 1/9") becomes `(blue + 3) / 8` (which the compiler would probably optimize into "shift right by 3 bits").

Answer (score 1):

As a previous student of cs50x, I also got the same issue in this pset, Make a copy of the image and then using that, calculate the rest as if we change the original values, then the average will not reflect the correct result.
Also, check this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59305240/cs502019-problem-set-filter-blur-somehow-not-working-correctly) , it describes the same issue in the community.